# TortoiseSVN - Repo-browser button

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In order to fix a working copy problem in **Tortoise SVN**, a colleague, suggested me to  the following steps: 
1. Launch Repository Browser by clicking **"Repo-browser"** in the menu. 
2. Locate the locked file. 
3. Right click your mouse on the locked file. 
4. Click "break lock".

However, I didn`t find the **"Repo-browser" button**. Anyone knows where I find it?

Thnaks!

Comment: Right click on your checkout copy of svn repository, you will find this option.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal/ command prompt and change directory to the location where you have .svn file.

Then run the below command:

```
svn cleanup
```

This command should release all the break locks.

Comment: Thanks! However, I`ve already done the cleanup (Break locks) and the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I clicked in TortoiseSVN -> Get lock... 
Then I selected the files with the option Steal the lock.
After that, I clicked in Realeased the lock...
And all the users were finally able to edit.